# On page refresh, the data stored in array becomes clear

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage, page-refresh

**HTML**

```
<body onload="load()">
    <button onclick="notes()">Click Here</button>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let array = [];
    let text = "Hello!";

    function load(){
        //when this function is loaded on doing refresh, the data in array becomes [0].
        let y=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes"));
    }
        
    localStorage.setItem("note", JSON.stringify(text));

    function notes() {
        let z = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("note"));
         array.push(z);
         console.log(array);
        localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(array));
    }
    </script>
```

Each time I click the button, the text in localstorage comes into the array but the problem is when I refresh the page, the load function occurs, I get the data for the first time and then also data stored in array gets clear or set to [ ].
Kindly suggest any solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small typo in your `load` function as you are trying to get the data of the key `notes` but in the `notes` function you are trying to get the data of the key `note`.

Update your statement in the `load` function to:

```
let y=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("note"));
array.push(y)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assign the value from `localStorage` to your `array` var

```js
let array = [];
let text = "Hello!";

// initialize array from storage
function load(){
  array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes")) || [];
}

// update both the array and local storage
function notes() {
  array.push(text);
  localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(array));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what's your intention here but try to **change the first line of** `notes()` **function** this way

```
let z = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes"));
```

Note the **localStorage key in plural**

I also encourage you to use constants to avoid this kind of errors:

```
const NOTES_COLLECTION_LS_KEY = "notes";
```

Or something less verbose maybe.